# does linq where call reduce calls to my database (Custom built)

Tags: c#, linq, yield

I have a method that gets rows from my database.  It looks like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> GetRowsIter()
{
    _resultSet.ReadFirst();
    do
    {
        var resultList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < _resultSet.FieldCount; fieldIndex++)
        {

            resultList.Add(_resultSet.GetName(fieldIndex), 
                           _resultSet.GetValue(fieldIndex));
        }
        yield return resultList;
    } while (_resultSet.ReadRelative(1));
    yield break;
}
```

This is great when I want to return all the rows.  But sometimes I want to return only some of the rows.

I am planning on writing my own method (`GetRowsIterWhere(string column, object whereValue)`), but I am wondering if I can use the linq where on my method.

I admit I don't know how it would work, becuase I am advancing the reader with a ReadRelative(1) to get to the next value.  So even if it "thinks" it is skipping rows, it will not really skip them.

I am really concerned with performance here (I am currently refactoring from Linq-To-Datasets because it was way way way too slow.)

So, my question is, do I need to write my own `Where` type method or can I change the one above to work with the linq `where` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use LINQ `Where`, but you'll need to build the predicate yourself. It isn't tricky. Something like (from memory; no compiler to hand):

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "row");
var body = Expression.Equal(
               Expression.PropertyOrField(param, column),
               Expression.Constant(whereValue));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(body, param);
```

then:

```
IQueryable<T> source = ...
var filtered = source.Where(lambda);
```

This will cause the `Where` to be executed at the server (for example, in TSQL), removing most of the network IO (asusming a sensible filter).

Comment: WOW.  I thought I was fair to decent at C#, but I don't even know where to plug this in.  I will have to do some research before I can use it.

Comment: @Vaccano - re your comment; for example, with LINQ-to-SQL, `yourDataContext.SomeTable` is an `IQueryable<YourType>`.